# proper use of class and types

Tags: haskell, types

I am currently working on a project that is related to physics. I want to improve my already working program and give it more structure.
But at the moment I am going in circles and not making progress.

I want to build green's functions, but I also want to be very general, so that I can reuse my library, of course.

I would like to have a class that holds the green's function based on the problem, this can be free space, or a resonator or something else. And the functions also depend on the gauge. In gauge 1 I get a representation of green's function like this:

```
greenF_Gauge1 :: (Scalar a -> a) -> (Scalar a -> a) -> Scalar a -> Scalar a -> Scalar a
```

But in Gauge 2 I have one argument more and a different return type

```
greenF_Gauge2 :: (Scalar a -> a) -> (Scalar a -> a) -> Scalar a -> Scalar a -> Scalar a -> Scalar a -> Complex (Scalar a)
```

It would be nice to have only one function for the green's function and just select the correct one by the type of the Gauge. And building on that I want to create the correct function based on the nature of the problem (free space etc.)
Since I have different numbers of arguments and different return types I somehow failed at the class definition.

I tried:

```
type GreenFC a =  ((Scalar a -> a) -> (Scalar a -> a)  -> Scalar a -> Scalar a -> Scalar a)
type GreenFL a =  ((Scalar a -> a) -> (Scalar a -> a)  -> Scalar a -> Scalar a -> Scalar a -> Complex (Scalar a))
type GreenMix a = (GreenFC a, GreenFL a)
data ResultType a  = Clomb (GreenFC a) | Lrenz (GreenFL a) | Mix (GreenMix a)

class  (VectorSpace a) => GreenFunc g a  where
  greenF :: g -> ResultType a
```

But when constructing the actual functions based on my structure, I have a problem accessing the return values, which are functions hidden in `ResultType`. I think there must be a more elegant way to do this.

I would like to use the power of the type system and make the whole program more abstract, so that I can exchange the gauge for example and don't have to hack in my code. But currently my level of understanding is that I know about type families etc but I still don't know how to apply them properly.
Any hints in that direction are very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to abstract over, because you are talking about stuff like greens and gauges instead of functions and I don't know what those are or how you would want to abstract them (I suspect other potential answerers are in this boat). Do you have a concrete example of some repetitive stuff you have to write now, and a more abstract way you wish you could write it?

Comment: Even knowing what Green's functions are, it's not clear what you actually want to do with them.  Are you integrating them over something?  Often it's best to not start with the most general case.  Start by writing the code for both Coulomb and Lorenz gauges, then identify what code they share and use that as a guide for generalizing the code.

Comment: I admit I was maybe to straight forward. I want to have a function, the Green's function, based on my individual problem. For case A I have a specific function which returns a real number. But for case B the function returns a complex number and also receives an additional input argument. Now I want to be very flexible and have one function for based on the problem. Of course I want to integrate over this function. But this is another story. Basically it is this: Environment leads to -> Case 1 -> Case 2 -> ... -> Case n => Each Case has a function based on an additionial parameter like Gauge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I don't know if this makes any sense physically, but looking at your code I'd be tempted to do something like the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data GreenParamFC a = GreenParamFC {
       gpFC_f1, gpFC_f2 :: Scalar a -> a
     , gpFC_s1, gpFC_s2 :: Scalar a
     }
data GreenParamFL a = GreenParamFL {
       gpFL_f1, gpFL_f2 :: Scalar a -> a
     , gpFL_s1, gpFL_s2, gpFL_s3 :: Scalar a
     }
data GreenMixParam a = GreenMix {
       gm_FC :: GreenParamFC a
     , gm_FL :: GreenParamFL a
     }

class GreenParams p where
  type GreenResult p a :: *
  greenF :: p a -> GreenResult p a

instance GreenParams GreenParamFC where
  type GreenResult GreenParamFC a = Scalar a
  greenF (GreenParamFC f1 f2 s1 s2) = ...

instance GreenParams GreenParamFL where
  type GreenResult GreenParamFL a = Complex (Scalar a)
  greenF (GreenParamFL f1 f2 s1 s2 s3) = ...

instance GreenParams GreenMixParam where
  type GreenResult GreenMixParam a = (Scalar a, Complex (Scalar a))
  greenF (GreenMix
              (GreenParamFC f1 f2 s1 s2)
              (GreenParamFL f1 f2 s1 s2 s3)
         ) = (..., ...)
```

Comment: This looks very nice. I want to learn more about the type system and its possibilities, that's why I would like to follow this approach. @viorior's version looks also very elegant, but I prefer the classes now. I will accept your answer.

Comment: And it makes absolut sense physically. In electrodynamics you have a certain variability in the way you define your problem. Based on your gauge, your equations change, although the overall result is the same. This can lead to either simple or more complicated calculations. Ideally, you find a solution or design of your equations that is gauge invariant. But that might be complicated :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with different number of arguments.

The simplest way is to use data type for "parameters". And to use data type for "result".

And to use just pattern-matching instead of class.

Something like that:

```
type GreenMix a = (Scalar a, Complex (Scalar a))
data ResultType a  = Clomb (Scalar a) 
                   | Lrenz (Complex (Scalar a)) 
                   | Mix (GreenMix a)

data Gauge a = Gauge1 (Scalar a) (Scalar a)
             | Gauge2 (Scalar a) (Scalar a) (Scalar a)

greenF :: (Scalar a -> a) -> (Scalar a -> a) -> Gauge a -> Result a
greenF f1 f2 (Gauge1 g1 g2)    = Clomb $ greenF_Gauge1 f1 f2 g1 g2
greenF f1 f2 (Gauge2 g1 g2 g3) = Lrenz $ greenF_Gauge2 f1 f2 g1 g2 g3
```